# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException json requete post

Tags: android

```
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://recrutement.stb.com.tn:1010/PlateformeApi_Externe/api/Authorize/");
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList< NameValuePair >(5);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "sami"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "stb"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("AuthMethod", "FormsAuthentication"));


            try {
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                Log.d("myapp", "works till here. 2");
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    Log.d("myapp", "response " + response.getEntity());
                    String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ok"+responseBody,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }



    });
```

}}

```
              android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Comment: Paste your code in async task in onbackground method

Answer (score 0):

Place your code above in such a method:

```
public void callToNetwork(){
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://recrutement.stb.com.tn:1010/PlateformeApi_Externe/api/Authorize/");
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList< NameValuePair >(5);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "sami"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "stb"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("AuthMethod", "FormsAuthentication"));


        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            Log.d("myapp", "works till here. 2");
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                Log.d("myapp", "response " + response.getEntity());
                String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ok"+responseBody,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }}}}
```

Create an inner class as follows:

```
public class logIn extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
     callToNetwork();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Results from method if    any", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    //Show something on ui like Progress Dialog etc here
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
}
```

Then create an instance as such:

```
logIn logIn = new logIn();
logIn.execute();
```

Comment: thanks a lot but I have a problem in the display of the "responseBody" variable Toast.makeText (getApplicationContext (), "ok" + responseBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG) .show (); !!!!

Comment: That should go in the onPostExecute method.If thats your question otherwise state the problem clearly